# Angularjs array changes reference after splice

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I am using angularjs for my project and its working fine. Today I am facing little but different problem 
so just need some kind of suggestion.
Consider code :

```
$scope.deleteEmpty = function(){

    for(var sp=0;sp < $scope.column.length;sp++){

        var offerings = $scope.column[sp];

        if(offerings.spName == -1){

            $scope.removeanswer(sp);                        
        }
    }
},

$scope.removeanswer = function(position){

    for(var question=1;question<$scope.rows.length;question++){

        $scope.rows[question].answerlst.splice(position, 1);
    }
},
```

here i am deleting answerlst according to offerings position, it is getting deleted but the there is one problem. Consider one example:

```
$scope.column = [{'spName':'-1',spId:'1'},{'spName':'-1',spId:'2'},{'spName':'-1',spId:'3'},{'spName':'-1',spId:'4'}]
```

when first time call to `$scope.removeanswer(sp);` it delete answerlst for first column but after that the position of answerlst get changed. So it deletes for 1st and 3rd position and not for the whole.

Any suggestion please.
Thanks.

Comment: What is in $scope.rows ?

Comment: suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co that replicates your issue. Hard to understand what the issue is from your description. We also can't see where you call `deleteEmpty()` from

Comment: @ Robin Elvin question with answer list in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution could be improved if there was more information.

The idea is to store the column indexes in a `toRemove` array and then remove them all at once from the `answerlst` of each question.

```
$scope.deleteEmpty = function(){
    var toRemove = []; // column indexes to be removed

    for(var sp=0;sp < $scope.column.length;sp++){
        var offerings = $scope.column[sp];
        if(offerings.spName == -1){
            toRemove.push(sp);                        
        }
    }
    $scope.removeanswer(toRemove);
},

$scope.removeanswer = function(positions){
    for(var question=1;question<$scope.rows.length;question++){
        $scope.rows[question].answerlst = $scope.rows[question].answerlst.filter(function(value, index) {
          return positions.indexOf(index) < 0;
        });
    }
},
```